# Leaflet PlayBack

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-draw, leaflet-plugins

I am trying to animate with the https://github.com/linghuam/Leaflet.TrackPlayBack plugin. I have approximately 100 coordinates and ID numbers defined in each coordinate. Can different symbols be used for each id number I want?

[image: 1]

[image]

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', './data/test.json', false);
xhr.send(null);
const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
const map = L.map('mapid').setView([33.74, 134.38], 6);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

const trackplayback = L.trackplayback(data, map, {
  targetOptions: {
    useImg: true,
    imgUrl: './ship.png'
  }
```

Can different ids be used instead of ship.png in each id?

```
l = n.a.Class.extend({
        trackPointOptions: {
            isDraw: !1,
            useCanvas: !0,
            stroke: 1,
            color: "red",
            fill: 8,
            fillColor: "red",
            opacity: .5,
            radius: 4
        },
        trackLineOptions: {
            isDraw: !1,
            stroke: !0,
            color: "#1C54E2",
            weight: 2,
            fill: !1,
            fillColor: "#000",
            opacity: 2
        },
        targetOptions: {
            useImg: !1,
            imgUrl: "../../static/images/ship.png",
            showText: !1,
            width: 8,
            height: 18,
            color: "#00f",
            fillColor: "#9FD12D"
        },
        toolTipOptions: {
            offset: [0, 0],
            direction: "top",
            permanent: !1
        },
        initialize: function (t, i) {
            if (n.a.extend(this.trackLineOptions, i.trackLineOptions), n.a.extend(this.targetOptions, i.targetOptions), n.a.extend(this.toolTipOptions, i.toolTipOptions), this._showTrackLine = this.trackLineOptions.isDraw, this._map = t, this._map.on("mousemove", this._onmousemoveEvt, this), this._trackLayer = (new c).addTo(t), this._trackLayer.on("update", this._trackLayerUpdate, this), this._canvas = this._trackLayer.getContainer(), this._ctx = this._canvas.getContext("2d"), this._bufferTracks = [], (this._trackPointFeatureGroup = n.a.featureGroup([]).addTo(t)), this.targetOptions.useImg) {
                const t = new Image;
                t.onload = (() => {
                    this._targetImg = t
                }), t.onerror = (() => {
                    throw new Error("img load error!")
                }), t.src = this.targetOptions.imgUrl
            }
        },
```

I want the color value of trackLineOptions in this code to change the color according to each data in json.

````
var b = data;
for (i=0; i<data[0]; i++) {
    b= data[i] }
console.log(b)

if (b = b[0]) {
var trackPointOptions= { isDraw: !1,
useCanvas: !0,
stroke: 1, 
color: "blue", 
fill: 8, 
fillColor: "yellow", 
opacity: .5, 
radius: 4 } };```



in this code I tried to create a loop and change the color
````

Comment: Do you have several tracks and want to have different icon for each track? Or you want to have different icon for each track point on the same track?

Comment: Actually what i want is that each id draws a different color line.

Comment: Then please edit your question and clearly state what you actually want. Where would you get info which color goes to certain id?

Comment: I edited it the way you say

Comment: After looking at the internals of `Leaflet.TrackPlayBack` plugin, I'm afraid it's not possible, not even by some simple extension. You would have to do a lot of code modifications on several places.